# insert MySQL from Google sheet

Tags: mysql, google-sheets-api

I need to insert a Google spreadsheet information into a MySQL table database automatically every 2 h. Can someone help me, please?
I have already used import tool in phpMyAdmin, but manually, and I need to do it  automatically.
Maybe it can be with importmysql or load data infile script. But I need some guidelines, I'm not a programmer, however I can learn the basics to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this forum: [Google Apps Script to Export Spreadsheets to mySQL execute on multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390687/google-apps-script-to-export-spreadsheets-to-mysql-execute-on-multiple-files):

> If your MySQL instance is a **public-facing instance, accessible from outside your local network**, you could use [Google Apps Script JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/) to connect to your MySQL instance and insert/update data from your google sheets. Please read the [Setup for other databases section of JDBC guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#setup_for_other_databases) for details on setting up your database for connection from Google Apps Script.

You can have one script that loops through all spreadsheets in a given folder and inserts data from each into your MySQL database.